# C# - I can't make my rowheader invisible with DataGridTableStyle

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

When I used a DataGridTableStyle to format my Datagrid, the
   RowHeadersVisible stopped working, then I saw on the internet I
   should use the DataGrid.RowHeadersVisible, and then I tried, but it
   says there's no such method. What could be wrong ?

I'm using .net compact framework 3.5, could this be the problem ? If
   this method isn't avaiable, is there another way I could make the row
   header of my grid invisible ?

*This is my code:*

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = tabela;

DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
ts.MappingName = tabela.TableName;
DataGridColumnStyle celId = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
DataGridColumnStyle celQuantitem = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
celId.MappingName = "PRODUTOID";
celId.HeaderText = "Id";
celQuantitem.MappingName = "QUANTITEMSEPARADO";
celQuantitem.HeaderText = "Separado";

celId.Width = 50;
celQuantitem.Width = 75;

ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(celId);
ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(celQuantitem);
ts.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the row headers of a compact framework DataGrid just use:

```
dataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

DataGridTableStyles.RowHeadersVisible is not supported.

Comment: Then you need to post your full code. I tested with your code as base and it works fine.